# How to Enable ssh-agent on Git-Bash using VS Code

Tags: bash, git, ssh, ssh-agent

I use VS Code and Git-Bash for git commands **on Windows**, whenever I open it I need to set the ssh-agent and the SSH key address.

When researching the subject I read several tutorials on how to configure ssh-agent when starting VS Code

I created a ***talsk.json***

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Inicial SSH",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "bash",
        "args": ["eval $(ssh-agent)",
            "ssh-add C://Users//my.user//.ssh//my-key-RSA"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

***tasks.json***

```
  {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
                "args": ["eval $(ssh-agent)",
                "ssh-add C://Users//my.user//.ssh//my-key-RSA"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create ***.profile***

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2=agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

**But it didn't work properly**

How do I make it so that when opening VS Code, git-bash starts running these two commands?

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ ssh-add C://Users//my.user//.ssh//my-key-RSA
```

I just need that when opening VS Code it loads git-bash and runs both commands. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How did it not work properly? Was there an error message?

Comment: If you're passing bash a script as an argument, it needs to follow the argument `-c`. `["bash", "...script here..."]` doesn't work (without `-c` it's expecting a filename, not code to run). And only the one argument _immediately after_ the `-c` is expected to be code; it's not one argument per line to code as you seem to currently expect. Mind, even then there's the additional problem that you want your shell to then become interactive.

Comment: And `.profile` is run for _login_ shells -- not noninteractive shells or non-login interactive shells.

Comment: If you want absolutely any kind of bash instance (be it interactive, non-interactive, or login) to run code from a file while it's starting up, put the name of that file in the environment `BASH_ENV`. (If bash is running in POSIX mode, the filename should instead be in `ENV`; this is one of the fairly few ways in which bash fails to comply with the standard when it's not explicitly in POSIX mode).

Comment: I just need that when opening VS Code it loads git-bash and runs both commands. What is the best way to do this?